# How to use mysqli_stmt_attr_get() and mysqli_stmt_attr_set() functions in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to use **mysqli_stmt_attr_get()** and **mysqli_stmt_attr_set()** function in php ?

I am on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.attr-get.php) for these functions but there is no example to understand them. I did experiment on them and [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.attr-get.php) states that **mysqli_stmt_attr_get()** returns the current value of the statement parameter but it always returns 0 or 1 which doesn't make any sense. There is no extra documentation, explanation or examples on the google regarding to these functions. All the websites have copied and pasted the documentation from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.attr-get.php) about these functions.

Can anyone tell how we use these functions. One example for each one will be more helpful.

Comment: Look at the doc for `attr_set()` to see what attributes you can query. If you dont understand what they are, it's probably best to ignore these 2 methods

Comment: **php.net** says about **mysqli_stmt_attr_get()** that it `Gets the current value of a statement attribute` and says that `Returns FALSE if the attribute is not found, otherwise returns the value of the attribute.` So when i use it, it always returns 0 or 1 instead of value of the attribute in the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what php.net says:

**mysqli_stmt_attr_get():**

> The attribute that you want to get.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.attr-get.php

**mysqli_stmt_attr_set():**

> The attribute that you want to set. It can have one of the following
>   values:

```
MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH : Setting to TRUE causes mysqli_stmt_store_result() to update the metadata MYSQL_FIELD->max_length value.
MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE : Type of cursor to open for statement when mysqli_stmt_execute() is invoked. mode can be MYSQLI_CURSOR_TYPE_NO_CURSOR (the default) or MYSQLI_CURSOR_TYPE_READ_ONLY.
MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS : Number of rows to fetch from server at a time when using a cursor. mode can be in the range from 1 to the maximum value of unsigned long. The default is 1.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.attr-set.php

**Basically it means:**

> `mysqli_stmt_attr_get()`: Used to get the current value of a statement
>   attribute
>
> `mysqli_stmt_attr_set()`: Used to modify the behavior of a prepared
>   statement

**Result**: think best is to skip these functions. There are no to less examples on the internet to explain these, which makes it hard to use them.

Maybe you can explain in a question what needs to be done and another working would fix your code instead of using one of these. Still a good question tho! I hope someone else could explain exactly what these functions are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqli_stmt_attr_set` you can set three settings that should probably never ever be used.

- `MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH`
  This tells mysqli to calculate the maximum length in bytes for each column when the values are fetched from the server using `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` function. This can easily be done in PHP and asking mysqli to calculate this length automatically causes unnecessary performance costs. This has been removed in PHP 8.1.
- `MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE`
  This setting tells mysqli to open a cursor on the MySQL server for this result set. A cursor will behave like an unbuffered result in PHP except that the data will be buffered on MySQL server. This can be useful when you want to use a second prepared statement at the same time without buffering the data from the previous one yet in PHP. However, buffering result sets in PHP will probably be more efficient most of the time and easier to manage. Of course, using cursors and calling `mysqli_stmt_store_result` or `mysqli_stmt_get_result` would contradict itself.
- `MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS`
  This setting doesn't do anything. It's supposed to tell the library how many rows to fetch when using cursors, but this functionality has not been implemented. If you use libraries other than mysqlnd, they might implement this feature.